# The number of the concurrent tcp/ip sessions

Tags: internet-explorer, concurrency, tcp, wireshark, sessionid

I want to count the number of the TCP sessions that internet explorer setups for  a specific application? I do know how to increase the limit of concurrent sessions in internet-explorer but I do not need it. I want to count and keep the instant number of the sessions? Is wire shark or another tool useful? If yes how to write a count query?

Answer (score 0):

many sinffer tools count the TCP sessions.
One free tool: http://www.athtek.com/netwalk/free.html